# create vector of array of string and void function pointer in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, std

how to create an array or vetor like this in python:

this program in python:

```
a = [["foo",foofunc]["bar",barfunk]]
```

an array (or any thing) with another **multi type** array in,

Comment: You may create a class with 2 elements, a string and a function, and then create a `std::vector` of such objects. For the function, you may use [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: Maybe what you need is `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, void(*)()>>`.

Comment: `std::variant` is like a *union* which means only a single type can be active at a time. It's most definitely not an "array". Besides, an `int` can't be used to represent a function or other callable object.

Comment: Alternatively, since your use case is unspecified, `using myfunc = function<void()>;` and `map<string, myfunc> a;`.

Comment: Provide a short bit of python code that is what you want to do.  It should be both minimal and complete.  What you have written does not describe your problem well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a `vector` of `pair<std::string, void (*)()` as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
void foofunc()
{
    std::cout<<"foofunc called"<<std::endl;
    //do something here 
}
void barfunc()
{
    std::cout<<"barfunc called"<<std::endl;
    //do something here 
}
int main()
{
    //create a vector of pair of std::string and pointer to function with no parameter and void return type
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, void (*)()>> a;
    
    //add elements into the vector
    a.push_back({"foo", &foofunc});
    a.push_back({"bar", &barfunc});
    
    //lets try calling the functions inside the vector of pairs
    a[0].second();//calls foofunc()
    
    a[1].second(); //calls barfunc()
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/1J9FgkcNd).

Comment: i use your code. on compile, g++  returns:/usr/bin/ld: test/header_test: _ZSt4cout: invalid version 3 (max 0)
/usr/bin/ld: test/header_test: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

Comment: Try the following command: `g++ main.cpp -o program` In the above command, main.cpp is the name of the source file. So if the name of your source file is different than main.cpp then use that name in the above command instead of main.cpp.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of `std::function` as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


void foofunc( )
{
    // your code goes here
    std::clog << "Hi" << '\n';
}

int main( )
{
    std::function< void( ) > f_foofunc = foofunc;
    f_foofunc( ); // call it directly

    std::vector< std::pair< std::string, std::function<void( )> > > func_vec;

    func_vec.push_back( { "foo", &foofunc } );
    
    func_vec[0].second( ); // call it from the vector
}
```